# app center in uwp causes server execution failed 0x80080005

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, comexception, visual-studio-app-center

I am using **AppCenter** in my **uwp** application and to use it I have following code in my **app.xaml.cs** constructor, just after **initializecomponent()**

**Code** ( where exception occurs )

```
AppCenter.Start("{appCenterSecret}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Push), typeof(Crashes));
```

> Note that app was running fine for many days with this line of code before, and without making any changes suddenly it caused this problem.

**Exception**

{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
   at Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.CreatePushNotificationChannel(Action`1 created)
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.ApplyEnabledState(Boolean enabled)
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.OnChannelGroupReady(IChannelGroup channelGroup, String appSecret)
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.StartService(IAppCenterService service)
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.StartInstance(Type[] services)
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart(String appSecret, Type[] services)
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start(String appSecret, Type[] services)
   at FluentVideoPlayer.App..ctor()
   at FluentVideoPlayer.Program.<>c.b__0_0(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams p)}

**Exception StackTrace**

"   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)\r\n   at Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.CreatePushNotificationChannel(Action`1 created)\r\n   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.ApplyEnabledState(Boolean enabled)\r\n   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Push.OnChannelGroupReady(IChannelGroup channelGroup, String appSecret)\r\n   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.StartService(IAppCenterService service)\r\n   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.StartInstance(Type[] services)\r\n   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart(String appSecret, Type[] services)\r\n   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start(String appSecret, Type[] services)\r\n   at FluentVideoPlayer.App..ctor()\r\n   at FluentVideoPlayer.Program.<>c.b__0_0(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams p)"

**Note**

I was not getting this error before but I am getting it after updating to vs 2017 15.7.2 version. and I can succesfully run the app if I run it directly without visual studio. but when i try to debug i get this exception.

min verson : creators update

target version: fall creators update

my OS version :171672 ( insiders build fast ring )

Comment: Did you intermittently get this exception or always? What's your OS build version? And what's your project's target/min version?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT please see the question now I have added more info

Comment: To determine if not SDK issue, can you try calling directly `var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();` (from Windows.Networking.PushNotifications namespace) in your app? Can you test on another machine with no insider OS build? Have you tried run VS as admin?